# Disable hardware acceleration, backward compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility

I have a problem with a function (`setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null)`) available in api >=11, and my code should run on android 1.6 (API level 4) too.
I have tried to use reflection like this:

```
try {

        Method method = View.class.getMethod("setLayerType", Integer.TYPE, null);
        method.invoke(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("_________________test", "Function not found");
    }
```

but my app crash at view.setLayerType with java.lang.VerifyError....

Does anybody have any idea how can I workaround this crash and get a backward compatibility with this function in lower level api?

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove

```
view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
```

and you should be fine, for security reasons, Java/Android would first verify that it has at least a shot of running a given class before proceeding, and on older Android OS it doesn't know how to execute "view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);", it would throw a hard Error before *any* code from that class could be run.

Since you've run the code using reflection, you shouldn't need that line of code anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This should be useful: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html

If it really has something to do with hardware acceleration, you could add following to your manifest:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

src: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: `android:hardwareAccelerated` is available from api level 11, so I can't use it

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work with your code. The problem I found was on the method type parameterization. Also you weren't invoking the method on the view you wish to set hardware acceleration. This was my solution:

```
public static void setHardwareAccelerated(View view){
    try {
        Method method = View.class.getMethod("setLayerType", int.class, Paint.class);
        method.invoke(view, View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RD", "Hardware Acceleration not supported on API " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actualy does nothing. You can not currently turn hardware acceleration for single view. According to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: @snapix you can turn OFF but you can't turn ON.

Comment: @DuyenHangKim you can turn it ON by calling: `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);`