# Remove fragment crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, error-handling, actionbarsherlock

I  add and remove fragments like this :

**ADD**

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top, R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
                                .add(R.id.fragment_explore, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
ActivityMain.BACKSTACK_EXPLORE.add(fragment);
```

**REMOVE**

```
Fragment depopFragment = BACKSTACK_EXPLORE.get(BACKSTACK_EXPLORE.size() - 1);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom, R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top)
                                                .remove(depopFragment)
                                                .commit();
                    BACKSTACK_EXPLORE.remove(depopFragment);
```

There is a fast slide animation. The fragment comes from bottom and goes back to bottom.

My issue is when you press the back button (depop the fragment) and before the animation is finished you touch the activity that is appearing behind.

It gives me a simple Fatal signal 11 error (more often on samsung galaxy s3)

Any idea ?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but keeping fragments (which store Context) in a static container is bad practice. It may lead to context leak.

Comment: Reptification : this only happen on samsung galaxy s3 (android 4.3) never on nexus4(android4.4). This only happen when removing the fragment. Only if i click on the "fragment1 behind" while the removing animation of "fragment2 above" is still going on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved it, it was related to onCreateAnimation() that i used to know when the animation was finished

```
view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
```

this line was doing the crash. It seems to be related to hardware acceleration and most likely only on android 4.3

see this link : [Disable hardware acceleration, backward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886772/disable-hardware-acceleration-backward-compatibility)